# How to find span with class string by specific substring in the class python

Tags: python, html, date, beautifulsoup, calendar

I am downloading some data using Beautifulsoup. I extract the code, it looks like this.

```
<td><span class="calendar-date-2">11:50 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="ABC"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>SEP</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-1">12:00 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="CDE"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>OCT</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-3">12:10 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="FGH"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>NOV</span>
```

I need to get the {time, title, month}  into one df. This needs to select by the substring "calendar-date" in class attr.

I want to use

```
bs4.find_all('span',{class: XXX})
```

But this requires the class has the exact attrs.

I don't know how to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try css selector without regex.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

datahtml = """<td><span class="calendar-date-2">11:50 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="ABC"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>SEP</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-1">12:00 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="CDE"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>OCT</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-3">12:10 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="FGH"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>NOV</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(datahtml, "html.parser")
for span in soup.select("[class^='calendar-date-']"):
    print(span.text)
    print(span.find_previous('td').find_next('div')['title'])
    print(span.find_next('span').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `span` tags and then filter them out:

```
spans = [s for s in bs4.find_all('span') if s.get('class', [''])[0].startswith('calendar-date')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<td><span class="calendar-date-2">11:50 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="ABC"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>SEP</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-1">12:00 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="CDE"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>OCT</span>

<td><span class="calendar-date-3">12:10 PM </span></td>,
<tr><td>
<div title="FGH"></div>
</td></tr>
<span>NOV</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for span in soup.find_all("span", class_=re.compile(r"^calendar\-date\-\d+")):
    print(span.text)
    print(span.find_previous('td').find_next('div')['title'])
    print(span.find_next('span').text)
```

**Output:**

```
11:50 PM 
ABC
SEP
12:00 PM 
CDE
OCT
12:10 PM 
FGH
NOV
```